# Is working in central bank haram which does not provide loans nor keep deposits based on interest?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, banking, work

So far I know that working in riba-based bank is not allowed. But for central bank, which does not provide loans nor keep deposits based on interest, will it be permissible to work on the central bank (Central Bank of BD -Bangladesh Bank)?.